# Finding the expected value for $f(x)=2 x\sin(x) e^{-x}$

Tags: statistics

To find the expected value for $f(x)=a x\sin(x) e^{-x}$ for $0<x<\infty$ 0 otherwise would I have to do the following since $E(x)=u_x$

$E(X)=\int x f(x)dx$ so would I have to compute $\int_{0}^{\infty}2x^2\sin(x)e^{-x}$ to find the expected value.

Comment: You can only take expected values of a random variable.  Where is your random variable?  What is its distribution?  What does $f(x)$ have to do with the problem?  (that is certainly not a density, as $f(x)=a x \sin(x) e^{-x}$  can be negative over $0 < x < \infty$)  What is $u_x$?

Comment: It says on my book the continous random variable x has joint probability density  $f(x)=a x sin(x)e^{-x}$

Comment: $u_x$ stands for the mean of the random variable

Comment: Do you agree that function can be negative?

Comment: sorry I forgot to write the integral

Comment: I guess the function can be negative in that case its not a pdf I guess my teacher made a mistake with the homework...

Comment: Yes.  Your general approach of finding the $a$ constant to satisfy $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x)dx=1$, and then integrating to get $E[X]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x)dx$ is correct. But in this case that density does not make sense since it is negative for certain intervals. It gives $P[X \in [4, 5]] = \int_4^5 2x\sin(x)e^{-x} dx < 0$ which does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

To provide an "answer" to my comment above:

The "density" $f_X(x) = 2 x\sin(x) e^{-x}$ for $x\geq 0$ cannot be a true density because it is negative over certain intervals.   It would give $P[X \in [4,5]] = \int_4^5 2x \sin(x)e^{-x}dx < 0$ which does not make sense. So this is likely a mistake in the question.

However, it is correct that $\int_0^{\infty} 2x \sin(x) e^{-x}dx = 1$ (and so the $a$ constant needed to ensure the integral is 1 is indeed $a=2$). The general computation $E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf_X(x)dx$ would be correct if this density $f_X(x)$ made sense.